# How to see NaN values in Pandas with read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Data, and read this from txt File, but have a Problem.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("df.txt", sep =";")
df.set_index(["Name", "Day"], inplace=True)
```

But i see not all indexes.

It looks like: 
[image: Image 1]

df.txt:
[image: Image 2]

How can i see Peters day 2 and 3 (from image) with Nan values?

Comment: Can you include an image of the df.txt?

Comment: I did. df Image in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reindex` to the cartesian product of the level values:

```
import pandas as pd

df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))

#         Breakfest  Lunch  Dinner
#Anna  1        5.0   11.0     9.0
#      2        6.0    9.0    10.0
#      3        1.0   10.0     8.0
#      4        7.0   11.0    11.0
#Peter 1        6.0   12.0    10.0
#      2        NaN    NaN     NaN
#      3        NaN    NaN     NaN
#      4        4.0   10.0     9.0
```